# Cost to cancel or change an unfilled Augur order

Tags: fees, augur, 0x

With the launch of Augur v2, what is the cost to cancel a previously entered order that has not yet been filled? Is this cost the same as the cost to modify the order by changing the bid, ask or quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Open Orders on Augur have an expiration time.  By default they are set to the markets Resolution Begins time.  Users can change the time to expire earlier.  If an order expires on it's own, these orders will cost nothing to expire.  If a user cancels an existing open order it will cost gas to cancel this order.